# error CS0234: The type or namespace name `iOS' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEditor'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, daydream

I have installed the latest versions of Unity (2017.3.1), Daydream SDKs (GVR SDK for Unity v1.130.0) and followed the steps here: https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/unity/get-started#configure_build_settings_and_player_settings

However when I press Play I get the following error, ideas on what is the reason & how to fix it?

> Assets/GoogleVR/Editor/GvrBuildProcessor.cs(20,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'iOS' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Edit: Issue fixed after a few hours of submission on GitHub with the release of GVR SDK for Unity v1.130.1

Comment: From the Build Settings, switch your platform from whatever it is currently set to to iOS or Android.

Comment: I had done it as it was stated in the steps but had not worked. Though now I tried it with the previous Daydream SDK 1.120 and now having another issue: "Virtual Reality SDK Daydream is not supported in Editor Play Mode. Please Build and run on a supported target device.
Attempting to enable None instead." Is this expected ?

Comment: File for bug report on for GoogleVR on their github page. Also mention your plugin and Unity version

Comment: filed the issue with SDK 1.130 though considering SDK 1.120 had been around for a while I doubt that is also a bug. Any other thoughts?

Comment: The problem is coming from their SDK so yes

Answer (score 19):

If you're facing with this problem there are 2 steps to solve it:

1. Make sure that "**iOS Build Support**" is checked in **Unity Hub -> Installs** as *Adam* mentioned (if U're developing for iOS platform then this option most definitely is already checked).
2. Place your script in **Assets -> Editor** folder. *UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode* namespace cannot be used in your main project. It works only in special *Assembly-CSharp-Editor* project intended to modify native Xcode project. (That's the option that worked for me after searching a ton of forums).

Comment: If "iOS Build Support" is not enabled, then it can be added via "Add Module" option.

Comment: #2 is a clutch find - thank you for documenting your hours long search so the rest of us don't have to

Answer (score 4):

The Official Solution:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unityeditor-ios-xcode-ios-namespace-doesnt-exist.365381/

Step by step I did:
Figure 1 shows the Unity Download Assistent installation file that should be run.

[image: Figure 1 - Unity Download Assistant]

Figure 2 shows the "iOS Build Support" option that should be checked for installation.

[image: Figure 2 - Unity Install iOS Build Support]

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and changed the "Current Platform" to "iOS" in Unity Hub, This is a quick fix and it works now.

**Change "Current Platform" to iOS Image**:
[image: Change "Current Platform" to iOS Image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed IOS build through unity hub while the project is open, try restarting Unity Hub and Unity Editor. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when **iOS Build Support** is not installed in **Unity Hub**

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue When useing unity-arkit-plugin to develop something, i did nothing but import this plugin it throw this error .
And after i installed UnitySetup-IOS-Support-for-Editor-2017.3.0f3.pkg ，the issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If IOS support is installed through Unity Hub after the editor is opened save the project, close and reopen.